# Serialize object with an array in it

Tags: c#

I have this class :

```
[Serializable]
class Data
{
  int data1;
  int data2;
  Other_Data[] array;
}
class Other_Data
{
// I have some ints and bool here
}
```

The question is how do I serialize/deserialize a object of type Data with a single file

Comment: @Rufus L nothing I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type `Other_Data` is serializable too, then this should cause you no problems. Just know that serializers require the types and properties or fields to be public:

```
[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public int data1;
    public int data2;
    public Other_Data[] array;
}

[Serializable]
public class Other_Data
{
    public int someInt;
    public bool someBool;
}
```

And then for example using the [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

```
var obj = new Data() {
    data1 = 5,
    data2 = 7,
    array = new Other_Data[] {
        new Other_Data() { someInt = 1, someBool = true },
        new Other_Data() { someInt = 2, someBool = true },
        new Other_Data() { someInt = 3, someBool = false }
    }
};

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);

Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try it out, Just another quick question this will work with the `BinaryFormatter` too right ?

Comment: @UriPopov Yes, although `BinaryFormatter` is a bit stricter than `XmlSerializer` (latter doesn’t require `[Serializable]` for example). But yes, it works with the types in my example.